# Objective C: Comparison issue between numbers

Tags: objective-c, ios, comparison, nsnumber

I am trying to implement the code snippet below. However I am unable to get my expected results. For example if my disanceFromLoc = 0.16, I am still getting my output as 0.16 km.

Is there something wrong with the way I am comparing the value? object is of 'NSNumber' class (defined it as double in core data)

```
if ([object.distanceFromLoc doubleValue] < 0)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Approx. Distance: %0.2f m", [object.distanceFromLoc doubleValue]*1000];
    }
    else 
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Approx. Distance: %0.2f km", [object.distanceFromLoc doubleValue]];
    }
```

Thanks!

Zhen Hoe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you mean to compare to one, not zero.

As it stands, you're checking if your `distanceFromLoc` is negative, which (presumably) never happens with a regular distance. Instead, you should be checking if you're closer than 1km (i.e. `< 1`), at which point you can multiply by 1000 and convert to meters.